# Gridview OnItemClickListener not working with cardView

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, android-cardview, onitemclicklistener

I want to implement an `OnItemClickListener` for my gridView.

I define the listener like so in my fragment:

```
    GridView gridview = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("imagedata","Position clicked: "+ position);
        }
    });

    List<ItemObject> allItems = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getTinkeractivities(); //getJSON data
    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), allItems, "home");
    gridview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

My Layout for each item in the `gridView` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="false"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
card_view:cardElevation="4dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/screen_shot"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/screen_shot"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/screen_shot"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/theme_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/activity_name"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/activity_name"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

However, the click listener doesn't seem to be working. I tried setting `android:clickable` to `false` in all child views of the card View and also tried setting it to `false` on the cardview itself but to no success.

I am able to successfully set a click listener in my `CustomAdapter` for each row view but I don't want to take that approach because I want to do some batch selection using a [custom action bar](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB) on my gridview using the standard implementation. Otherwise I will have to mess around with `longPress` events and have a `checked` state for my row items and then struggle with implementing the Custom Action Bar from within the adapter.

To have a clean implementation, I want to define the `click` listener in my fragment. I read several blog posts and related answers on Stackoverflow all suggesting to go with the adapter approach and none specifying how to get it working in an activity or a fragment the proper way.

I want to know if it's impossible to set an `OnItemClickListener` in my case. If no, then how can I go about debugging this and fixing the problem?

Comment: maybe wrap `CardView` inside `RelativeLayout`. that should work.

Comment: Use a linear layout for cardview

Comment: @VoraAnkit, it is not a repetition for the question you just posted. The OP there wants to have different click listeners for sub items in his gridView implementation. I want to implement an `OnItemClickListener` for my grid view. The problem is it's not getting called may be because of the card view. Other elements i have in the layout namely `ImageView` and `TextView` shouldn't interfere with the clickability of the row I guess.

Comment: @AkshayBhat, You mean put the cardView inside a linear layout?

Comment: @vrundpurohit, tried your approach. Put the `CardView` inside a `RelativeLayout` but to no avail :(. How can I debug this problem? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

To your grid items

---

EDIT :

Else if you have buttons that can block the click you can add :

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: Where should I add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`. In the `CardView` widget item? Also, I don't have any buttons. I just have an imageview and 2 text views inside my layout..

Comment: Aah, added it to my `RelativeLayout` inside which I put my `CardView`. Set `android:focussable = false` on my `CardView` and put `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in my `RelativeLayout`. Works like a charm! :)

Comment: Yes add descendantFocusability in the parent layout :)